# How To Handle An Ignored Request

Tags: professionalism, communication, relationships, complaint

Where I work, we have a system to open tickets for any issues or service requests one might have.

In June, I created a ticket to have a phone installed in one of the rooms here.

The person in charge of fulfilling this request checked the wall ports of the wrong room and e-mailed me which ports were available there. I sent her a message through the ticket system that it was the wrong room and received no reply. I reached out again through the ticket system after a few months and still no response. Finally, I e-mailed her directly 2 days ago and I'm still not getting any response.

The ticket system shows you whenever someone has viewed the request so I know she has looked at the request and my comments a couple times over the past few months, but never responded.

I have no clue why she is ignoring me and I find this extremely infuriating, but don't know how to handle the situation. What should I do at this point?

Comment: Raise a new ticket linking to the old ticket copying in her boss? Someone else might pick it up?

Comment: @Michael - She's the only one here that handles this type of request. If I opened another ticket, I guarantee you it would get assigned to her again by a 3rd party that doesn't know what's going on and it will continue to be ignored for whatever reason.

Comment: Why the downvote and votes to close for my question? An explanation would be nice if this question is a duplicate or off-topic or something, but as far as I know it isn't.

Comment: Probably because this will depend on how your workplace is structured, and no one here knows that

Comment: If that is an issue with my question, then constructive criticism that would allow me the chance to update the question is better than downvoting and voting to close it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Given that you've reached out to this person multiple times at this point with no response, the next step is to **escalate**. Either send a ticket / email to a more senior ticket-handler (referencing the earlier tickets and your responses) or to this person's supervisor (again, referencing the earlier tickets and your earlier email).

> Jim,
>
> I filed ticket [ticket #] on [date], but it was completed incorrectly. I've filed subsequent tickets [ticket #s] and sent emails to [non-responder], but she isn't responding to any of my subsequent tickets or emails. Can we work together to get [original issue] cleared up?

Alternately, you can craft an email to your own supervisor, asking him / her to get involved:

> Bob,
>
> I sent the original request for a phone on [day x], but on [day y] it was installed in [other room]. I've replied to the original ticket [ticket #], as well as creating a new ticket [ticket #], and sent an email to [non-responder]. Given that I've been unable to make any progress on this issue, do you have any suggestions for what to try next?

Comment: Professional, and clear.

Comment: I've decided to take you advice and "escalate" it to my supervisor. Hopefully, I can get somewhere with this now. I'd love to know why she has been so unhelpful. I could understand if she's been busy, but this request was made in over 6 months ago, so there's no excuse.

Comment: Just a little update - I did escalate to my manager who said that he will take care of it at this point. At least there's a greater chance now that it will actually get done.

Comment: Sounds great! Hopefully your manager will have better luck getting a response from her. Also, you'll have established a minor workflow for this type of situation, so that if it occurs again, you don't have to wait 6-7 months to move forward.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say you should try more direct means of contact. Phone or even in person, if possible the second time around. I think it should always go in that order.

Email first -> Phone second -> In-person third.

Whenever you find that the method didn't get across, move to the next method. Usually it stops at phone, especially if you are being routed. ***"Oh, Pam isn't in this week because of ..."***, then you know where to turn next.

Comment: I just left her a voicemail which at this point I doubt she will respond to. The thing I don't get is why she's completely ignoring me. I've never even spoken with her before and see no reason for her to dislike me. I could try talking to her in person next if I can actually find where she is, but I'm leaning towards escalating the issue as Adam V suggests in his answer.

Comment: If she's really that incompetent to get back to someone, she needs to have her superiors emailed anyway. If this is important that you contact her, then she isn't doing her job, and ultimately, costing the company productivity.

Comment: I completely agree that she should be held accountable. I've contacted my supervisor who says he will take care of it.